# Inappropriate file type or format when open a zip file

Tags: macos, zip

When I tried to unzip a zip file in macOS 13.3.1, it shows an error like this:

[image]

I have tried to unwrap this file using unzip command:

```
> file file.zip
file.zip: Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract, compression method=deflate
> unzip file.zip
Archive:  file.zip
error [file.zip]:  missing 332593792 bytes in zipfile
  (attempting to process anyway)
error [file.zip]:  attempt to seek before beginning of zipfile
  (please check that you have transferred or created the zipfile in the
  appropriate BINARY mode and that you have compiled UnZip properly)
```

Am I missing something? what should I do to fixed this issue? this is the zip file info:

```
> ls -alh file.zip
-rw-r--r--@ 1 xiaoqiangjiang  staff   241K Jan  1 19:47 file.zip
```

Comment: It looks like the file is corrupted - you need to get the original zip remade

Comment: I'd try a different compression app, the built-in one isn't great with 'odd' formats.  - [Keka](https://www.keka.io/en/) is free & handles most things.

Comment: I'd recommend The Unarchiver. https://theunarchiver.com

Comment: @benwiggy - I normally would for 'general use' but Keka is even better if you get a really esoteric file. I actually use it as a 'reserve' for when The Unarchiver fails.